# Tips for using Visual Studio Typed DataSets?

Tags: .net, ado.net, dataset, strong-typing

When using strongly typed dataSets in Visual Studio 2005/2008, if the underlying database schema changes, the only practical way to refresh is to delete the dataset and recreate it from scratch.   This is OK unless I need to customize the dataset.

Customizing by extending the partial dataset class allows customizations to be retained, but then a simple FillBy() again becomes a long sequence of SQL.

Is there any way to resynchronize a dataset with the database schema without losing dataset customizations?

Answer (score 2):

If you are just making a simple change like adding a field to a table, then I right click on the table and click configure.  Go through the wizard again adding the new field, (or even replacing the select with select *) and it adds the field to the table and syncs up all the queries that you've built.  I've had tables with about 10 different custom queries and when I reconfigure the table the queries all updated properly.

Answer (score 2):

Because typed datasets use generated nested classes, customizations will often be lost.  What I do is generate the typed dataset, and then mark several classes as partial.  Then I create separate files containing a duplicate nested class structure (also marked partial).

This way I can regenerate my data set and the only  update I have to do is to go back and make them partial again.  My customizations are kept in separate files.

Answer (score 0):

Typed Datasets are evil. LINQ to SQL is what typed datasets should have been, so I like to think of it as Typed Datasets 3.0. I hope when they fold L2S into the Entity Framework they retain what makes L2S so good.

Comment: "Typed Datasets are evil" doesn't tell us very much.  What don't you like about them?

Answer (score 0):

I've been using typed datasets quite successfully in a number of web and windows projects. 
There was a bit of discovery in the beginning - learning all the quirks of the dataset designer and how to extend the dataset to provide more flexible connection configurations.
But once you get past that, generating a data access layer will be quick work.